# MS access- click a button, open a parameter (dropdown with options, not dates), open report based on selection

Tags: parameters, combobox, listbox, report, ms-access-2010

The title may have been unclear, but I currently have a button that opens a report. the report pulls from a query that has parameters set to "fromdate" and "todate". instead of using dates and parameters that pop up as blank text boxes, I would like to click the button, have a form pop up with a combo box to select from the options available (currently 23 options) and then click a button to make a report that only displays the record (1-23) selected. Any advice? I do not need any time constraints because as the databases get updated with more records, there would be more than 23 options to choose from.

I would need a few steps of help with most of the process as Im trying to reverse engineer from an established report and query it by a new set of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new form with a combo box and a button.
2. Set the record source for the combo box.
3. Under button on click event, write the code to open the report passing the where clause parameter (where clause is something like "MyFiled = " & MyComboBox).
4. For your original button on click event, write the code to open the just created form.

Comment: Hope this is clear enough. If not, I'll give you more details.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, I have a string of questions regarding opening a report and having it run a where clause parameter. Should the button run a query or open a report? im unfamiliar with using the string format and usually rely on Do or Run commands in sqling